# Toggle the div on redirecting to the link with ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Actually i have a doubt....

Lets say i have some list of item on URL `localhost/xyz/xyz/xyz`. The all the divs are having specific ID like `29631`,`29632`,`29633` etc.

```
<div id="29631">
   <div>
     .........
     <div>

     </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="29632">
   <div>
     .........
     <div>

     </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="29633">
   <div>
     .........
     <div>

     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So if i will give the URL `localhost/xyz/xyz/xyz/#29633` then that div can be loaded on the top of the list. Can we do it in script or PHP ?

Any idea guys ? Please suggest me.

Comment: Did you try it with ID's that doesn't start with a number ?

Comment: Javascript `window.location.hash` should be a good start

Comment: @adeneo No the ID should be the numbers only

Comment: @user574632 How to use that ?? Any reference

Comment: @RIADev can't you simply google it..?

Comment: Well you can use that to retrieve the value `#value` in the url. What you want to do with it is beyond me - you dont say in your question.

Comment: window.location.href = "localhost/xyz/xyz/xyz/#29633"

Comment: @TJ Hey i know the rules....after google only i came here if any suggestion plz give me...

Comment: This is the default behaviour, when adding a hash the page is scrolled to that ID, but generally ID's should not start with a number so I was asking if you had tried it with ID's that actually start with a letter, as it should work out of the box in all browsers, that is with scrolling, to actually move the element you have to use javascript as the hash isn't available on the serverside.

Comment: @RIADev you were asking reference for `window.location.hash` that in itself is a reference.. you can simply google it directly and find info.. that's what i asked..

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try with this:

```
$(function(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash !== undefined || hash !== ''){
        $('div:first').before($(hash));
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay is there any thing we can do it by PHP ??